# Unable to append modal using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm unable to append a certain div to a modal when pulling in data using pnp and JavaScript.

The whole process explained:
Function DomyApiCalls - **WORKS** (Pulls in all the boxes with the titles)
Function filtering - **WORKS** (Filters the names in alphabetical order)
[image]

Function getModal - Doesn't work (I want it when a user clicks on a box, that the modal shows and just appends all the ***filesHtml*** to the .Modalbody class.

This is pulling in the page title, I need the folderName from below instead.
[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    DoMyApiCalls("boxWrap");

    var current_title = $(document).attr('title'); //CURRENT_TITLE is supposed to be the "FolderName".

    if(current_title == 'Acuvue') {
      getModal("Acuvue");
    }
});

function DoMyApiCalls(elementId) {
$.ajax({
    url:  "/bdm/business-development/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('CompletedSubmissionTiles')/Items?$select=EncodedAbsUrl,Title,Line1,Line2,Hyperlink,TargetWindow,DescriptionHTMLOption,Line1,TileOrder&$orderby=Title asc",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function (data) {
  if (data.d.results) {
   var object = data.d.results;
   var Line1var;

   for(var i = 0; i < object.length; i++)
   {
    if(object[i].Line1 != null) { // Covers 'undefined' as well
     Line1var = "<div class='Line1'>" + object[i].Line1 + "</div>";
    } else {
     Line1var = "";
    }
    
    $('#' + elementId).append("<div class='col-md-4 box' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal"+object[i].TileOrder+"' id='TileBox"+object[i].TileOrder+"'><div id='titleBox' class='titleBox'><h1>" + object[i].Title + "</h1><div style='width:250px; height: 130px;background-color: white; border: 1px solid lightgrey;'><img style='width: auto; height: inherit; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block;' src='" +  object[i].EncodedAbsUrl + "' alt='" + object[i].Title +"'/></div></div></div>");
    
    filtering(object[i].Title);     
     }  
    }
    }         
  });
};

function filtering(title) {
    var filter = "Name eq '" + title + "'";
    
    $pnp.setup({
        baseUrl: "/bdm/business-development/"
    });
    
    $pnp.sp.web.folders.getByName('Completed Submissions').folders.filter(filter).expand("Files").get().then(function(data){    
    });
}

function getModal(folderName) {
 
  $pnp.setup({
  baseUrl: "/bdm/business-development/Completed%20Submissions/"
 });

 $pnp.sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/bdm/business-development/Completed%20Submissions/" + folderName).files.orderBy("Name").get().then(function(f) {

  var files = '';

  $.each(f, function(index, value){
   var filesHtml = "<div class='file'>" + 
        "<a target='_blank' href='" + value.ServerRelativeUrl + "?web=1'><img src='//PublishingImages/wordThumbSmall.png'/></a>" + 
        "<a target='_blank' href='" + value.ServerRelativeUrl + "?web=1'><p id='fileTitle'>" + value.Title + "</p></a>" + 
       "</div>";
   
   files = files + filesHtml;
  });
  $(".Modalbody").append(files);
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><div id="x">&times;</div></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">

                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="FT-main-category" style="margin-top:0px;">
                    <div class="FT-main-header ms-WPBody"><strong><span style="color: white;">Files</span></strong></div>
                    <div class="Modalbody">
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: we'll need a bit more info than "doesn't work". What debugging have you done? If the code doesn't do what you want, what _does_ it do? Errors? Unexpected behaviour? Please clarify

Comment: I basically have to target var `current_title = $(document).attr('title');` to `object[i].Title` within DomyApiCalls. `$(document).attr('title');` doesn't give me the foldername.

Comment: eh? What does that have to do with your modal? Are you describing a separate problem here, or what?

Comment: Because when the title matches "Acuvue", that should trigger the getModal() function I hope.

Comment: well you haven't shown us the relevant HTML so we have no idea if you defined it properly. It's also unclear how it has any relationship to the code within DoMyApiCalls

Comment: So the way that I currently have it, is that the getModal() function will be called and `filesHtml` will be called and append it to .Modalbody

Comment: I understand that, but you're asking about why `$(document).attr('title');` doesn't contain the right value. I can't tell you that because I can't see the relevant HTML of your page.

Comment: To be honest though if you want to get the page title, you don't need jQuery. `document.title` will do the job perfectly well.

Comment: I'm sorry it's confusing, I've updated a screenshot above. So Instead of the page title, I need to target the FolderName from DoMyApiCalls.

Comment: Ok. And before you mentioned that the foldername is within `object[i].Title`, right? So in the DoMyApiCalls callback you can write `getModal(object[i].Title);` and open the modal that way. The only problem I can see is that `object` could have many items in it. And you don't want to open a modal for all of them at once, I think? They would just over-write each other. Earlier, you mentioned about responding to a click on an image. Is it the images created in the line `$('#' + elementId).append...` within the callback, which you want to handle the clicking on? That part I'm not clear about still

Comment: That is correct, the elemendId append is creating the boxes and giving them special ID's that I wanted to link to a modal "number".

Let's just say each box will open a modal but the content within that modal will be pulled from different folders under the SharePoint Document library.

The "Acuvue" box will open a folder called "Acuvue" in the library and display all the contents in the modal.

Comment: ok so first thing you need to do is attach a "click" event to each box. In the click event you then call "getModal" with the correct ID. Since you know the ID of the box you just created, you can create a unique click handler for it fairly easily. Do you know how to create a "click" event handler using jQuery?

Comment: I don't, but I will do some research online to see what I can find.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/click/ would be a sensible place to start :-)